# How to prove that two variables have the same first digit by modular arithmetic?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, decimal-expansion

How could I find that x and y have the same first digit(Like, 52, 2 is the first digit here. Just an example) by using modulo arithmetic?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean, Do you seek an algorithm to test if $x$ and $y$ have the same units digit?

Comment: @BillDubuque yep

Comment: The units digit of $x$ is its remainder $\,x\bmod 10.\,$ So you need only compare those remainders (or, equivalently, test if their difference $\,x-y\,$ has remainder $0)\ \ $

Comment: $a \equiv b \pmod {10} \iff $ $a$ and $b$ have the same digit in the "one's" position.  What more needs to be said?

Answer (score 0):

If we write $x$ in decimal expansion: $$x=\overline{a_n....a_2a_1a_0}=10a+a_0$$ where $a =\overline{a_n....a_2a_1}$, and $$y=\overline{b_m....b_2b_1b_0} = 10b+b_0$$ then $x-y = 10(a-b)+(a_0-b_0)$, so if $a_0=b_0$ then $10\mid x-y$ which means:

$$ x\equiv y{\mod 10}$$

Comment: But I don't understand it. Can you please explain more? Why did we divide by 10?

Comment: @TechnoKnight because we use a base $10$ number system. If it was binary we would use $2$ instead.

Comment: @TechnoKnight Because [we use base $10$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal).

Comment: @J.G. So if I find x = y mod 10 then they have the same digits, right?

Comment: Yes.......................

Comment: @TechnoKnight The same *last* digit.

Comment: @J.G. Thanks for everyone who helped me.

Comment: Are you accepting the answer or not?